# Manager isn't available while setting up django-fmc

Tags: python, django, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to get django-fmc set up with Django (v 1.97, Python v2.7.12, djangorestframework v3.3.3) to handle storing registration ids and sending notifications to devices. I am following the [tutorial they provide](http://django-fcm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending_device.html) but it doesn't seem to be working.

I am getting the following error when running my local server and *python manage.py fcm_urls*:

```
...
File "C:\Work\Dev\LiveTracking\Api\app\views.py", line 50, in DeviceViewSet
queryset = Device.objects.all()
File "C:\Work\Dev\LiveTracking\Api\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 277, in __get__
self.model._meta.swapped,
AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'fcm.Device' has been swapped for 'app.MyDevice'
```

I don't want to add additional fields to the MyDevice model for now. I've looked all over but can't fix this error. If anyone can shed some insight into this error it would be much appreciated.

Here are some of my code snippets:

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'fcm',
)

# Firebase Cloud Messaging Key
FCM_APIKEY = 'AIzaSyCaqHZIcaGDOpfTZUmAHEowsqD-fCtow6A'

# Location of device model
FCM_DEVICE_MODEL = 'app.MyDevice'
```

serializers.py

```
from fcm.models import Device

class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ('dev_id','reg_id','name','is_active')
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from fcm.models import Device
from fcm.serializers import DeviceSerializer

class DeviceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Device.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DeviceSerializer
```

urls.py

```
from rest_framework import routers
from fcm.views import DeviceViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'devices', DeviceViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^v1/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Comment: Since you've swapped the Device model for app.MyDevice, why are you using the original in the serializer rather than your swapped version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`swappable` is an [undocumented feature](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19103), actually only supposed to be used for custom `User` models. [The doc on custom user models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model) clearly states that once you use a custom user model, directly referencing `contrib.auth.models.User` won't work:

> If you reference User directly (for example, by referring to it in a foreign key), your code will not work in projects where the AUTH_USER_MODEL setting has been changed to a different user model.

You probably want to read the rest of this chapter FWIW.

To make a long story short: as Daniel Roseman mentions, you very probably want to use your own `MyDevice` model instead of the default `Device` one. And eventually contribute back a patch to `django-fcm` doc if it solves the issue.

Comment: After I get this project running I'll be sure to patch the outdated/incorrect documentation.